# CakePHP accessing other controllers

Tags: php, cakephp

CakePHP Newbie :)

I am having trouble accessing another controller and passing that data to a view in one of my controllers:

In `controllers/landings_controller.php`:

```
var $uses = 'User';

function home() {
    $userdata = $this->User->read();
    $this->set(compact('userdata'));
}
```

In `views/landings/home.ctp`:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->userdata;       
?>
```

When accessing `/landings/home` I get the following error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$userdata [APP/views/landings/home.ctp, line 38]
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.  Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->set('userdata', $userdata);
```

Compact returns a single array. $this->set expects two parameters.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/57/Controller-Methods

**Correction:**
set does in fact accept associative arrays (thanks Daniel Wright). Read below about using variables in views.

Also, variables are placed in scope -- not attached as members -- so you wouldn't do this in the view:

```
<?php echo $this->userdata ?>
```

but, rather:

```
<?php echo $userdata ?>
```

Assuming $userdata is a scalar, of course.

Comment: In fact, `$this->set` does work as the original poster suggests. If an array is supplied as a parameter, `$this->set` uses the array's keys and values instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `compact` is fine.You need know more about [set()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/57/Controller-Methods#set-427).